How do I implement a dual task classification experiment using keras and tensor flow
I am talking the following code (written for an earlier version of Tensorflow from the book Transfer learning for NLP).
input1_shape = (len(train_x[0]),)
input2_shape = (len(train_x2[0]),)
sent2vec_vectors1 = Input(shape=input1_shape)
sent2vec_vectors2 = Input(shape=input2_shape)
combined = concatenate([sent2vec_vectors1,sent2vec_vectors2])
dense1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(combined)
dense1 = Dropout(0.3)(dense1)
output1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='classification1')(dense1)
output2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='classification2')(dense1)
model = Model(inputs=[sent2vec_vectors1,sent2vec_vectors2], outputs=[output1,output2])

model.compile(loss={'classification1': 'binary_crossentropy', 
                    'classification2': 'binary_crossentropy'},
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit([train_x,train_x2],[train_y,train_y2],
                    validation_data=([test_x,test_x2],[test_y,test_y2]),
                                     batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, shuffle=True)

The code above worked with older versions of Tensor flow: < 2.0
I have been trying to get it to run on TensorFlow version: 2.16.1 and made the following changes
input1_shape = (len(train_x[0]),)
input2_shape = (len(train_x2[0]),)
sent2vec_vectors1 = Input(shape=input1_shape, name="vector1")
sent2vec_vectors2 = Input(shape=input2_shape, name="vector2")

class ConcatenateLayer(Layer):
    def call(self, inputs, axis=0):
        return tf.concat(inputs, axis=axis)
    


combined = ConcatenateLayer()([sent2vec_vectors1,sent2vec_vectors2],axis=0)
dense1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(combined)
dense1 = Dropout(0.3)(dense1)
output1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='classification1')(dense1)
output2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='classification2')(dense1)

model = Model(inputs=[sent2vec_vectors1,sent2vec_vectors2], outputs=[output1,output2])
model.compile(loss={'classification1': 'binary_crossentropy', 
                    'classification2': 'binary_crossentropy'},
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', 'accuracy'])

history = model.fit([train_x, train_x2], [train_y, train_y2],
                    validation_data=([test_x, test_x2], [test_y, test_y2]),
                     epochs=10, shuffle=True
                    )

I keep getting incompatible shape errors like:
Incompatible shapes: [64,1] vs. [32,1]
     [[{{node gradient_tape/compile_loss/binary_crossentropy_1/logistic_loss/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_8871]


I have tried different batch sizes in the fit function and also tried reshaping the data. I tried to follow the error down into the tensorflow code but all to no avail.
the shape of the data is as follows:

Object name: train_x Shape: Shape: (1400,600)
Object name: train_x2 Shape: Shape: (1400,600)
Object name: train_y Shape: Shape: (1400,)
Object name: train_y2 Shape: Shape: (1400,)
Object name: test_x Shape: Shape: (600,600)
Object name: test_x2 Shape: Shape: (600,600)
Object name: test_y Shape: Shape: (600,)
Object name: test_y2 Shape: Shape: (600,)

And
Input shapes:

sent2vec_vectors1: (None, 600)
sent2vec_vectors2: (None, 600)

Output shapes:

output1: (None, 1)
output2: (None, 1)

I feel I am missing something. I am struggling to find good reference examples of a similar approach in 2.16.1. Any suggestions.
I have tried reshaping the data and tried a range of batch sizes, but I am very new to tensor flow.
